# How do I access a field of an object from the object it contains

Tags: java, object

Okay let's say I have a Class Game. I instantiate Game as game. Now game contains an object, startupState. How do I change an int in game from startupState?

Sorry if i worded this poorly... code example:

```
public class game{
    int state;
    StartupState startupState;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game();
    }
    public Game(){
        state = 0;
        startupState = new StartupState();
    }
}
```

So with this code how would I change state from the startupState object?

Comment: Have you learned about field access expressions and mutators/accessors? Don't answer that, go look it up.

Comment: is "game" supposed to be "Game"? Also, try a setter.

Comment: You can't change an instance of `Game` from `StartupState`. Your depencies are the other way around: `Game` knows about `StartupState`, but `StartupState` doesn't know about `Game`.

Comment: Could you post the definition of `StartupState`?

Comment: Anyway the code looks wrong, the class name is *g*ame the constructor have "public *G*ame". You create an object of type *G*ame with the name of *g*ame. Really this code compiles ok?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno typo i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a `Game` object from `StartupState`. The latter is an instance of a separate class, which may well exist without an instance of `Game`. You can, however, go the other way round, and change `startupState` from `game` (unless it's declared `final`). To change `state`, you will either need a setter (to access it from outside the current package) or you need to declare it `public`. Then, you can do

```
game.setState() // with setter
```

or

```
game.state = some_int // if it's public
```

Comment: Oh, duh, i'll just make it public

Comment: That, if you notice, is a minor issue. As I mentioned -- and Jeroen commented -- you can't change an instance of `Game` from `StartupState`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I interpreted this question correctly. So I assume that an instance of `StartupState` has a `initialState` member variable, maybe with a `public int getInitialState() {...}` instance method that returns it. In that case... theres no really straightforward way to change the `state` member variable of a `Game` instance from *within* the `StartupState` class (I am assuming thats what you want to do here). To do that, you must call `getInitialState()` from a instance method of the `Game` class and set `this.state` to the return value from the `getInitialState()` call.